# How to use preventDefault for a <a> in a table row

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html table like below:

```
<table id="tabRoom" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; width: 950px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="ui-widget-header">ID</th>
      <th class="ui-widget-header">Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="gridrow" onclick="editRoom(650);">
      <td class="ui-widget-content myclass" style="width: 10%;"> 
        <a style="display: inline;" href="/Config/Rooms/303">ID01</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        John Brown>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want is to prevent user direct to /Config/Rooms/303 when they click to the value of ID, but the users should see the popup coming from editRoom(). I need to use e.preventDefault() as far as I understand from what I read online, but I couldnt find the way of using it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: Couldnt find the answer still. I am trying the code below, not working. Please help.

```
$(".myclass").click(
            function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('prevented');
            }
          );
```

Comment: Do you have JS code?

Comment: $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: Why don't you just remove the link if it has no purpose at all ?

Answer (score 0):

To make it clean, why don't you put the redirect code inside the onclick event function?

`<a style="display: inline;" href="#" onclick="editRoom(650); return false;">ID01</a>`

JS: `funciton editRoom(id){
//do Something
window.href.locaiton ='/myurl';
}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to add a js code to prevent user going to href link. I shouldnt change editRoom(650) place

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('table a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        //display popup
    });
});
```

Comment: $(window).load(function(){ }) => $(function(){  })

Comment: this is not preventing for me?

Comment: So what @xAqweRx, you can write that in at least 5 different ways and it works, no reason for a downvote on a working solution. Emes Uras you must be doing something wrong because this definitely prevents a click on links inside a table.

Comment: @MarioPlantosar I haven't down voted you. It's just assumption. Or someone had bad mood

Answer (score -1):

kind of code for answer.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("popup");
for( var i =0; i< elements.length; i++){
elements[i].addEventListener("click", function( e ){

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", this.getAttribute("href"), true);
  xhttp.send();
  
e.preventDefault();
});
  }
```

```html
<a style="display: inline;" href="your_linnk_here" id="id01" class="popup">ID01</a>
<div id="popup"></div>
```